# Create cluster wide service account to connect with gitlab

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a self hosted gitlab and I want to deploy applications. I am trying to deploy a runner so that gitlab can connect to the kubernetes cluster. My kubernetes cluster is RBAC enabled.

Here is my gitlab-ci.yml for the runner:

```yaml
services:
  - docker:18-dind
    
stages:
  - deploy
      
deploy:
  image:
    name: thorstenhans/helm3:latest
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
    kubernetes:
      namespace: runners
  script:
    - echo ${CI_JOB_NAME}
    - helm version
    - kubectl version
    - helm repo add gitlab https://charts.gitlab.io/
    - helm install gitlab/gitlab-runner --version 0.20.0 -f values.yml
```

Here is the values.yml file:

```yaml
## The GitLab Server URL (with protocol) that want to register the runner against
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/README.html#gitlab-runner-register
##
gitlabUrl: https://gitlab.mydomain.com/
    
## The registration token for adding new Runners to the GitLab server. This must
## be retrieved from your GitLab instance.
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/
##
runnerRegistrationToken: "registration code here"
    
## Set the certsSecretName in order to pass custom certificates for GitLab Runner to use
## Provide resource name for a Kubernetes Secret Object in the same namespace,
## this is used to populate the /etc/gitlab-runner/certs directory
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/tls-self-signed.html#supported-options-for-self-signed-certificates
##
#certsSecretName:
    
## Configure the maximum number of concurrent jobs
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-global-section
##
concurrent: 10
    
## Defines in seconds how often to check GitLab for a new builds
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-global-section
##
checkInterval: 30
    
## For RBAC support:
rbac:
  create: false
    
  ## Run the gitlab-bastion container with the ability to deploy/manage containers of jobs
  ## cluster-wide or only within namespace
  clusterWideAccess: true
    
  ## If RBAC is disabled in this Helm chart, use the following Kubernetes Service Account name.
  ##
  # serviceAccountName: default
    
## Configuration for the Pods that the runner launches for each new job
##
runners:
  ## Default container image to use for builds when none is specified
  ##
  image: ubuntu:18.04
    
  ## Run all containers with the privileged flag enabled
  ## This will allow the docker:stable-dind image to run if you need to run Docker
  ## commands. Please read the docs before turning this on:
  ## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html#using-docker-dind
  ##
  privileged: false
    
  ## Namespace to run Kubernetes jobs in (defaults to 'default')
  ##
  # namespace:
    
  ## Build Container specific configuration
  ##
  builds:
    # cpuLimit: 200m
    # memoryLimit: 256Mi
    cpuRequests: 100m
    memoryRequests: 128Mi
    
  ## Service Container specific configuration
  ##
  services:
    # cpuLimit: 200m
    # memoryLimit: 256Mi
    cpuRequests: 100m
    memoryRequests: 128Mi
    
  ## Helper Container specific configuration
  ##
  helpers:
    # cpuLimit: 200m
    # memoryLimit: 256Mi
    cpuRequests: 100m
    memoryRequests: 128Mi
```

How can I create a service account for gitlab so that it can deploy applications cluster wide?

Comment: Did you not find that the [supported mechanism for installing runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/13.3/ee/user/clusters/applications.html#gitlab-runner) behaved as you wished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this informations in gitlab [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/13.3/runner/install/kubernetes.html).

> **Enabling RBAC support**
>
> If your cluster has RBAC enabled, you can choose to either have the chart create its own service account or provide one on your own.
>
> To have the chart create the service account for you, set rbac.create to true:

```
rbac:
  create: true
```

> To use an already existing service account, use:

```
rbac:
  create: false
  serviceAccountName: your-service-account
```

---

So you would have to change your values.yaml to

```
rbac:
  create: false
  clusterWideAccess: true
  serviceAccountName: your-service-account
```

---

There is related documentation about rbac and service accounts.

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#service-account-permissions
- https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/authorization/rbac/
- https://www.magalix.com/blog/kubernetes-authorization

There is another stackoverflow post and a gitlab issue which should help with creating the service account for your use case.

- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/3841
- [how can I create a service account for all namespaces in a kubernetes cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63283438)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

- a [cluster-application](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/cluster-applications)

> End goal: Execute all helm operations as GitLab CI yml in the connected
> cluster repo (vs running on server).

- a Cluster management project template

See [GitLab 14.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/06/22/gitlab-14-0-released/#cluster-management-project-template) (June 2021)

> ### Cluster management project template
>
> In this release, we are moving away from the CI/CD template-based approach for cluster management.
>
> Cluster management is the ability to manage Kubernetes clusters to improve application availability running on a cluster.
>
> The old method hides too much of the logic, restricts customizations and extensions of your apps.
> With the new approach, you can easily create a cluster management project from a project template and fully control your applications.
>
> A project created using the new template contains the code needed for cluster management jobs, including [built-in support for several applications](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/management_project_template.html#built-in-applications). You can easily extend the project to other applications and own them completely.
>
> Additionally, new applications will be installed using Helm v3. If you have former GitLab Managed Applications installed using Helm v2, check the [Helm migration guide](https://helm.sh/blog/migrate-from-helm-v2-to-helm-v3/) and the [GitLab Managed Apps migration guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/migrating_from_gma_to_project_template.html). The CI/CD job output will also guide you through these migrations.
>
> In GitLab 14.0, the cluster management project supports only certificate-based cluster integrations. We plan to add support for the GitLab Kubernetes Agent in the next release.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_0/cluster_management_project.png -- Cluster management project template]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/management_project_template.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/327908).