# Pods in GKE return "error looking up service account" - how to correctly use a GCP service account in GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, service-accounts

I have created a GKE Service Account.

I have been trying to use it within GKE, but I get the error:

```
pods "servicepod" is forbidden: error looking up service account service/serviceaccount: serviceaccount "serviceaccount" not found
```

I have followed the setup guide in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform#gcloud_1).

1.Created a GCP Service Account called "serviceaccount"

2.I created, and downloaded the JSON key as key.json.

3.`kubectl create secret generic serviceaccountkey --from-file key.json -n service`

4.Added the following items to my deployment:

```
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: serviceaccountkey
        secret:
          secretName: serviceaccountkey
      containers:
        volumeMounts:
        - name: serviceaccountkey
          mountPath: /var/secrets/google
        env:
        - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
          value: /var/secrets/google/key.json
```

When I deploy this out, I get:
`pods "service-7cdbcc67b9-" is forbidden: error looking up service account service/serviceaccount: serviceaccount "serviceaccount" not found`

I'm not sure what else to do to get this working, I've followed the guide and can't see anything that's been missed.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Serviceaccount same  as pods a Namespaced service, is it in the same namespace?

Comment: Your Deployment template spec is wrong. Check the tutorial for the correct schema. The `containers` array needs a `name` and and an `image`.

Comment: This approach is a good "any Kubernetes" approach to mounting Service Accounts. If you're committed to GKE, there's a propriety approach called [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by using Workload Identity to bind the K8s Service account to the GCP IAM service account:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons for getting this error can be if you have created a service account in one namespace and trying to use that service account only for another namespace.

We can resolve this error by rolebinding the service account with a new namespace. If the existing service account is in default namespace then you can use this YAML file with the new namespace for rolebinding.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata: 
  name: kubernetes-enforce-default 
  namespace: <new-namespace>
roleRef: 
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io 
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: kubernetes-enforce 
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: kubernetes-enforce
  namespace: kube-system
```

Refer to this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63283438/how-can-i-create-a-service-account-for-all-namespaces-in-a-kubernetes-cluster) for more information.